# Can PHP and HTML code assist happen in the same file?

Tags: php, html, aptana, code-assist

I'm attempting to use Aptana for some web programming. For the most part, I'm impressed! One thing that's driving me crazy is that Aptana won't perform code assist on PHP code in an .html file... and conversely, won't perform HTML code assist in a .php file?!

Am I missing something here? Pushing "best practices" aside for a moment... PHP and HTML can live harmoniously in a single file. So how do I edit both languages in that same file?!

P.S. I've been using CODA, which has its equivalent called Syntax Mode. You can choose PHP-HTML... which is exactly what I need in Aptana!

Comment: Thanks, Marko... but I'm using a Mac.

Comment: Try Komodo - not as nice as Notepad++ (IMO) but nice enough.

Comment: Tried Komodo... kinda wonky on a Mac. I'll give it another look though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm also using Aptana or to be more precisely: Eclipse 3.4.2 + Aptana 1.5 + Aptana PHP Plugin. In my PHP files I do have HTML code assist. Make sure that in `Window->Preferences->General->Editors->File Associations` you have the Aptana PHP editor as the default editor for `.php` files.

But it is true, that you don't have PHP code assist within HTML files by default. So the easiest way to get this is also chosing the Aptana PHP editor for `.html` files.

Comment: I have associated .html files to the 'PHP Source Editor' in Aptana Studio 3. This still shows warnings as if it doesn't recognise the PHP code. There is no option to associate it specifically with an 'Aptana PHP editor'. Has anyone managed to get this working by "choosing the Aptana PHP editor for .html files"?

Answer (score 0):

Aptana Studio 3 does all HTML/JS/CSS/PHP code assists in php files. By default, html files will not include PHP code assist unless you associate html files with PHP editor.

Regards,
Max

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) recently. It will do code completion help/syntax highlighting for both PHP and HTML in the same file.

It's a free, endless trial for Windows/Mac/Linux. After a few weeks, though, I loved it enough to pay for the license.